# How to solve ASP.NET relative url issue when using subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My current ASP.NET root is `localhost:2343/Project/FleetUM`

the problem is, from javascript, if i make an AJAX request with url as `/{controller}/{action}` , the request is made to `localhost:2343/{controller}/{action}` instead of `localhost:2343/Project/FleetUM/{controller}/{action}` , can anybody help me how to solve this problem. Should i use URL rewrite for this?

Comment: Use `Url.Action` to generate the url instead of writing the url as string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should *rewrite*

This is what worked for me

```
        <rules>
            <rule platformId="wdpVpr" name="www.your-website-name.com virtual path rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.your-website-name\.com$" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/your-subfolder/" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/your-subfolder/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule platformId="wdpVpr" name="your-website-name.com virtual path rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^your-website-name\.com$" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/your-subfolder/" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/your-subfolder/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>


        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="www.your-website-name.com virtual path rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(?:your-subfolder|(.*//[_a-zA-Z0-9-\.]*)?/your-subfolder)(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="your-website-name.com virtual path rewrite">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(?:your-subfolder|(.*//[_a-zA-Z0-9-\.]*)?/your-subfolder)(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^301$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
```

I followed this 2-part tutorial. It's a great one http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send a request with url equal to:

```
~/{controller}/{action}
```

~ (tilde) usually refers to the home directory which seems to be `localhost:2343/Project/FleetUM` in your case